# Placing facet titles and the boxes in top left of ggplot2 panels

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, how can I place the titles of each facet in the top left corner inside the plot panels, rather than at the usual top, left, right, or bottom positions using facet_grid or facet_wrap?

[image]

Comment: Turn off the regular strips using the `strip.text` and `strip.background` theme elements, then add the labels manually using e.g. `geom_text` or `annotate`.

Comment: Thanks, agree. If strip cannot be manipulated that way then geom_text is the solution.